# MVC Use model property to create anchor tag on view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application, I recently added anchor tags in a page where a lot of actions are taken from.  The idea is that when you return back to the index you also supply the projectID that the action pertained to, and it will jump you down the page to the anchor matching that projectID.

This being said I have a page in which I'm seeking to create a link on the view back to the main project page, but provide a fragment so that it will jump to the appropriate section.  However I have thusfar been unable to use either @Html.ActionLink or any other method to appropriately take me to the fragment upon action.  I'll illustrate.

```
<a href="~/backlog/# + @model.ProjectID"><div class="btn">Done</div></a>
@{ <a href="~/backlog/# + @model.ProjectID"><div class="btn">Done</div></a> }
```

This is what I've been trying to do most recently, however the view doesn't seem to know what to do with it.

Then I've tried a more MVC style approach.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Done", "index", "backlog", null, null, @model.ProjectID.toString());
```

There's a "mega" overload that takes seven parameters I've tried to use, but it also does not like me trying to pass the model property as a fragment this way.

Ultimately I'd like to come out with just a simple anchor tag that once processed will appear

```
<a href="~/backlog/#projectID"></a>
```

If at all possible, all help is appreciated.

Comment: `"the view doesn't seem to know what to do with it"` - What does that mean?  When you use that first attempt, what is the resulting HTML?

Comment: Try `<a href="~/backlog/#@(model.ProjectID)"><div class="btn">Done</div></a>`

Comment: @David it provides me with 'model does not exist in the current context'

Comment: @DStanley I just tried this and it still provides me with "model does not exist in current context"

Comment: @wyijx: I think the property name is `Model`, not `model`.

Comment: @David You're correct, the issue was I was referencing `model` instead of `Model`.
`<a href="~/backlog/#@(Model.ProjectID)">Done</a>` provides the desired behavior.  Thank you guys a ton.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the "MVC" approach with ActionLink if you use the right [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    string protocol,
    string hostName,
    string fragment,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

If you use [named parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) as well then people will actually be able to read it:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Done", "index", "backlog", protocol: null, hostName: null, fragment: Model.ProjectID.toString(), routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Done")#@Model.ProjectID">backlog</a>
```

Comment: Tested and this works too.  However I already deployed with the previous solution David mentioned in the comments.